# Cant find the error on line 6

Tags: php, post

I am a new on php. Experimenting a lot with this. I wrote another code. But it showing error on line 26. I am unable to find the problem. Please check it out and tell me what the problem was.
 **result.php**

```
    <?php
if (isset ($_POST["name"])){
    $name=$_POST["name"];
}
if(isset ($_POST["yob"])){
    $yob=(int) $_POST["yob"];
}
if(isset ($_POST["wifename"])){
    $wifename=$_POST["wifename"];
}
if(isset ($_POST["wyob"])){
    $wyob= (int) $_POST["wyob"];
}
$currentyear=date("Y");
if($yob>=$currentyear){
    echo "Sorry {$name} you have not born yet.";
}
if($currentyear>$yob){
    $husbandage=$currentyear-$yob;
}
if($wyob>=$currentyear){
    echo "Sorry {$name} your mother in law is still virgin.";
}
else{$wifeage=$currentyear-$wyob;}
if($husbandage>$wifeage){
    echo "You are {"$husbandage-$wifeage"} years older than your wife";
}
if($husbandage<$wifeage){
    echo "You are {$wifeage-$husbandage} years older than your wife";}
    if($husbandage==$wifeage){
        echo "You and your wife are same age";}

?>
```

**agecalculator.php**

```
<html>
<title>Age Difference Calculator</title>
<body>
<form action="result.php" type="post">
    Your Name: <input type="text" name= "name"><br/>
    Year Of Birth: <input type= "text" name:"yob"><br/>
    Your Wife's Name: <input type="text" name="wifename"><br/>
    Your Wife's Year Of Birth: <input type="text" name="wyob"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `{int}$_POST["yob"];`?  Try `(int)$_POST["yob"]`

Comment: Ok i fixed it. But now the problem arised on line 24. Please tell me what mistake i have made at line 24?

Comment: (int) value instead of {int} value, meaning casting the "value" into integer value.

Comment: remove the last ";" from the 24th line, and add it after the $wyob

Comment: Ok i have removed it. Now it showing error on line 26. Please tell me how to fix line 26?

Comment: @supto Your code is soooooo wrong, too much errors

Answer (score 8):

the problem is

```
{int}
```

it should be

```
(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should change

```
$yob={int} $_POST["yob"];
```

For this:

```
$yob=(int) $_POST["yob"];
```